# Forced UEFI when installing 17.04. Way to undo this?

Tags: uefi

I stupidly forced UEFI installation and now my computer will not boot into my windows partition. Is there any way to undo this?

Comment: Is Windows installed in UEFI or Legacy?

Comment: It is intalled on legacy. Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: So Ubuntu boots successfully in UEFI mode?

Comment: I've stopped trying to run ubuntu as I'm afraid I'll mess something up worse. I just realized accidentally deleted the windows partition apparently and I'm now worried I won't be able to get it back

Comment: It wouldnt boot into the windows partition before that happened though, this wasn't the cause

Comment: Did you actually overwrite the Windows partition, or it just won't mount?

Comment: I think I accidentally overwrote it. I'm using partition recovery wizard but so far it has yet to find the partition

Comment: If you really did overwrite the Windows partition, then **DO NOT do *anything* to your HDD.** The more you use it the slimmer the chances of recovery become. I suggest you run `testdisk` from a live Ubuntu USB drive

Comment: I'll try that. Just a second

Comment: Is this something I could do from windows 7? I think that installing that to try to find a way to fix the problem is what caused the overwrite. I just remembered ubuntu would not boot once it finished installing. I'm sorry I'm so disheveled, I've been up for hours trying to find a way to fix this

Comment: To be more clear, I installed windows seven and could see the windows 10 partition but it would not boot into that partition. I had to "clean" the drive from diskpart in order to install windows 7. I'm not good with these things and didn't realize that meant wiping the drive. I was able to recover the partition from partitionrecovery wizard but had to redo the process and now the tool isn't finding the partition anymore.

Comment: Running `testdisk` from a live Ubuntu USB drive does not require changing anything on the HDD

Comment: Windows 10 from vendor is always installed in UEFI boot mode to gpt partitioned drive. Default install of Windows 7 from DVD is BIOS only to MBR partitioned drive. You have to convert Windows 7 to flash drive and make a few minor changes to make Windows 7 UEFI bootable. Conversion from gpt to MBR often is a total erase during install. There are both Linux & Windows tools to convert, but Windows 10 installed in UEFI on gpt would never boot in BIOS mode.

Comment: I'm now running testdisk but am not sure what to do with it. I've also found a data recovery tool that has found the deleted files (and I can get them back for the low price of $70) and I checked to make sure it was really then so I know they're still there somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments, it's clear that you're in data-recovery mode now. There are numerous questions here on this subject, but in brief, you may be able to use [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) to recover entire partitions or [PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) to recover individual files. These aren't the only tools that can do this, and it sounds like you've found at least one other. There are also professional data-recovery services -- you send them your disk and they recover your files. Such services are pricey, though. Whatever tools or services you use, this is likely to be a painful task, and it's very unlikely that you'll recover your Windows installation to a bootable state. You'll probably have to re-install Windows before moving on to a Windows/Ubuntu dual-boot.

To that end, it's important that you understand the difference between an old-school BIOS, the new-fangled EFI/UEFI, and the perils of the CSM. In sum:

- **BIOS** -- This was the original PC firmware. It was written in 16-bit code in 1980 or 1981 and is *very* primitive by modern standards. It's been holding back PC development for years. In late 2011, manufacturers began a stampede to replace their BIOSes with UEFIs, likely because Microsoft required a specific UEFI feature (Secure Boot) to certify hardware for Windows 8.
- **EFI/UEFI** -- This is the successor to BIOS. (UEFI is EFI 2.x. I generally use "EFI," as it's the more generic term, except when I really mean the 2.x version.) Confusingly, many people, and even companies, refer to EFIs as "BIOSes." Because EFI is such a radical departure from BIOS, though, using "BIOS" to refer to an EFI is a mistake, IMO, because it leads people to think the differences are smaller than they are. This leads to untold problems. Importantly, EFIs requires entirely new boot loaders compared to BIOS. Some boot loaders, like GRUB, have been ported to both types of firmware, which can help hide the differences; but others are BIOS-only (such as LILO) or EFI-only (such as the EFI stub loader).
- **CSM** -- The Compatibility Support Module (CSM) is a backwards-compatibility layer for EFI; it enables an EFI to launch an older BIOS-mode boot loader or OS. You can think of the CSM being to EFI much what `dosemu` is to Linux -- both tools let you run programs for an older environment (BIOS or DOS) on a newer and more capable one (EFI or Linux). The CSM is sometimes necessary, but if it's activated, it makes it uncertain which way a boot medium that supports both modes will boot. This in turn can lead to problems, including the one you encountered -- you told the installer to do something dangerous because you didn't understand the warning, and now you're picking up the pieces. For more on the CSM, see [this page of mine.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/csm-good-bad-ugly.html)

At this point in time, most people doing fresh installations to blank disks are best served by *disabling their CSMs* and installing all OSes in EFI mode. Fortunately, this is something of the default, since the vast majority of new computers come configured this way. Windows 7 and later, all current versions of Ubuntu, most other current Linux distributions, all versions of OS X/macOS that run on Intel-based Macs, and several more obscure OSes all support EFI-mode booting. Some very old or very obscure OSes don't support EFI, but they can often be run in a virtualized environment (via VirtualBox, VMWare, etc.) just as well as on the "bare metal." The most common path to CSM-related problems results from bad Internet advice to enable it, and/or people poking around in their firmware setup utilities to get around boot problems with an OS installer. (Recall that BIOSes and EFIs require different boot loaders. If an installation medium was improperly prepared, it may lack an EFI-mode boot loader but have a BIOS-mode boot loader, so enabling a CSM may seem to work around a boot problem -- but this just leads to bigger problems down the road.)

Based on your description, it sounds as if you enabled your CSM and (re?-)installed Windows in BIOS mode. Presumably you had some reason for doing this, but when you booted the Ubuntu installer in EFI mode, it set you on course for disaster. When it comes time to re-install, it's probably best to disable the CSM and go with an all-EFI installation. OTOH, if you had a compelling reason to boot in BIOS mode, you should at least be aware of what all this entails, so that you don't repeat the mistake, or make some other equally devastating mistake.